# Mac Homebrew - how does one report possible bugs?

Tags: homebrew

I went to [Link](https://brew.sh/).  It showed a command to get started with homebrew.  I copied and pasted it into Terminal.  It installed homebrew successfully.  Then I ran the command 'brew doctor'.  It complained:

```
Warning: You have leftover files from an older version of Xcode.
You should delete them using:
  /Developer/Library/uninstall-developer-folder
```

So I did.  Now 'brew doctor' reports:

```
/Users/chap$ brew doctor
Warning: You have not agreed to the Xcode license.
```

The Xcode icon has gone generic and won't launch.  The App Store thinks it's installed and won't let me reinstall it.

The biggest problem is that I can't figure out where to get help.  There are no forums that I can see.  The things I see linked from homebrew that seem "discussion oriented" have names like "git", "blog", "gist", "wiki", "twitter" ... none of which I know how to use.  I can't even find an email address!

How does one ask for help when problems using 'homebrew' arise?  On Stackoverflow?

EDIT: what I meant to ask is - how does one report a possible problem to those who are supporting homebrew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can report bugs at https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues. I think you need a GitHub account though.

Answer (score 0):

> How does one ask for help when problems using 'homebrew' arise?

As this very question (and some 375 others at the time of writing) proves, yes, the Stack Exchange community may well have answers for you.

> The Xcode icon has gone generic and won't launch

It sounds like your issue is not with homebrew at all (which, as you noted above, installed correctly and is now happily responding to your `brew doctor` command) but with Xcode.

I would start by googling for answers regarding your Xcode situation, perhaps starting with [this similar post](https://superuser.com/questions/450707/how-to-remove-xcode-warning-in-macports) on SuperUser.

Comment: It was homebrew that recommended I run a command to delete "leftover files from an older version of Xcode."  I think the authors of homebrew should know that this resulted in my largely gutting my *current* Xcode.  I have restated my question above: how does one contact the authors of homebrew?

Comment: I ended up deleting my entire Developer directory, and was then able to reinstall Xcode.  At this point homebrew was happy.